# Delete row in MySQL if any column has NULL value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to delete a row if any of the columns have a NULL value in them?  I know I could do it one by one and check the columns but I would like to do this programmatically in MySQL where it would scale if I had 4 columns or 4000 columns.  I believe I could do this with PHP, but I much rather do this in straight MySQL.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could add a `Not Null` flag to your SQL columns.

Comment: If you have a table with 4000 columns, you're probably doing something wrong :-)

Comment: @EmbraceNext 4000 columns or row?

Comment: you could use the information_schema.columns table to loop through all columns of that specific table in a procedure

Comment: Ok, I don't have 4000 columns but I think this should be able to be done without doing a delete statement with WHERE column1 is NULL, column2 is NULL.... etc.  I like the idea of looping through all of the columns.  Since I am pretty new with MySQL (started this week), i really have no idea where to get started on that.  I saw an example but couldn't make it it work.  Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: 4 or 4000, this kind of question IS often symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, since you just mentioned you are new to MySQL, your database design is new too and most probably does not have a lot of data as of now.

Why not kill the roots of the problem instead of letting those grow into a big tree and then looking for tools to cut all the branches first?

You should go ahead and use MySQL `NOT NULL` option and disallow null values for your column since you are deleting them. So if you don't need to keep any null values then you can simply disallow them and they will not be saved in the first place.

Queries come long after a proper database design, if your design does not match what your system requires then you can only optimize the queries to an extent. Base structure is the first thing you should learn and improve. Google and SO both are filled with thousands of articles on Efficient database design and some basic concepts to get started.

Comment: The question was more of a "How can this be done, or shouldn't this be able to be done?"  The DB was just for testing and I left the NULLs in on purpose.  Now the the testing is almost done, I saw this as a unique issue and wanted to see if it could be done in case I ever came across something like this in the wild.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are a thousand ways using which this can be done, but not everything that can be done should be done. Even if you eventually learn how to do that it will still not be a good database design. So why not make a good one from scratch and learn other beneficial things

Comment: The DB looks to be the way I want it.  The issue is in testing my PHP code, records are created in a loop by accident.  So I would like to delete those records to clean up the database.  So its just something I wouldn't using a lot, but I would love to have that piece of code for a these occurrences.  While my PHP code for doing this is working great, I would like to be able to do this in SQL in case of future projects.

Comment: Ah, the brick wall conundrum

Answer (score 1):

You could delete those records with without so much ORs:

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE CONCAT(column1,column2,column3) is null
```

It may not make sense to delete *what can be done*, but can use this trick to get *what should be done*.

```
INSERT INTO NEW_TABLE
SELECT column1,column2,column3
FROM myTable
WHERE not CONCAT(column1,column2,column3) is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this works in mysql because i can't test it (i edited the sql server code to may work with mysql)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
    BEGIN

     DECLARE COL varchar(4000);
     SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(C.COLUMN_NAME, ' IS NULL ' SEPARATOR ' OR ') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'tbl_a' INTO COL;
     SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM test WHERE ', COL);
     PREPARE stmt FROM @s; 
     EXECUTE stmt;
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END//
```

i am using the select statement to check you just need to change that to delete

Comment: Thank you Markus.  It is a tad late for me right now to go over everything in there so I can understand it.  I may come back tomorrow with questions.
If anyone is wondering, here is my PHP code for this:
`foreach ($games as $game) {
    if (in_array(NULL, $game)){
      $gameID = $game['id'];
      echo "<BR>";
      mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM game WHERE id = " . $gameID);
      echo "$gameID is deleted <BR>";
    } 
  }`

Comment: I couldn't get this to work in MySQL workbench.  It doesn't like the DECLARE part of the statement.  Says I have a syntax error.  I don't know enough yet to make the adjustments I need.